# asp.NET - how to make sure web.config is used for conectionstring (rather than app.config)

Tags: asp.net, connection-string

I have a MVC web site that worked well, until I moved it into test, where it fell over.  After some investigation If found that because I had split the 'model' into its own seperate project, the model was using the connectionstring from its own app.config (not the web.config of the website).

So I found an article somewhere (can't find the link now), showing how I can use the web.config instead - great, I got the site into test.

Unfortuanatly, the next time I tried to get the site implemented in test again, I got the same problem, and after a while discovered that somehow the app.config of my model had re-written the connection string DOH!

What is the best practice here?  I need the database configuration to be in a file that is easily changed by my system administrators

Comment: I think it's getting it from the Settings file in your Model project.  I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project has both an App.config and a Web.config file then you'll want to tie them together so they share the connection string.  Doing so is easy.  In the *.config files add the line:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="WebCS.config" />
```

The webcs.config will look like:

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="YourConnString" connectionString="Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=YourDB;User ID=SQLID;Password=Password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

This will permit you to reference the same connection string from multiple places and make it easy to have connection strings that differ on your dev, test and deployment servers.

**Update**: If you are doing TDD or are otherwise separating out your logic into a separate DLL you may have both types of .Config files and thus the issue that you raise.  Of course, a separate Business Logic DLL is a "best practice" for creating forms-based Web apps in ASP.NET.  For example, I place only UI code in the web site itself and then call into a DLL for all business-related and data handling logic.  This not only helps with a separation of concerns but it makes testing easy as well.

Comment: Your welcome.  Thanks for choosing this answer as "the answer."

Answer (score 2):

An ASP.NET application will never use app.config, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: The problem is that the class library (my DAL) does use the app.config (rather than the web.config).

Comment: No, it does not. What makes you think so? In .NET, there is never more than one config file per AppDomain, unless _the_ config file redirects part of the configuration to another. Are you perhaps using Settings in the library? If so, try changing a value from the app.config and see if it matters when running from ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

[Using WebConfigurationManager is the preferred way to work with configuration files related to Web applications. For client applications, use the ConfigurationManager class.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.aspx)